# Error de sintaxis en la clausula FROM

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, ms-access-2010

Tengo 2 preguntas en un solo tema. La siguiente función me trabaja en otros desarrollos con normalidad.

```
Public Function VerificaUsr(ID As String, Psw As String) As Boolean
    Dim Rslt As Boolean

    Rslt = Conectar()
    If Not Rslt Then Exit Function

    DBCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Login_Name='" + ID + "' And Password='" + Psw + "'"
    DBCmd.Connection = Conn

    Reader = DBCmd.ExecuteReader
    If Reader.Read Then
        Return True
    Else
        nEnt = nEnt + 1
        If nEnt > 2 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Ha excedido los intentos de Acceso!", "Acceso sistema de Transporte", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("ID de usuario y/o clave de acceso incorrectos", "Acceso sistema de Transporte", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Return False
    End If
    Conn.Close()
End Function
```

como se puede ver es para garantizar que el usuario que intenta entrar al sistema es válido. Pero en un desarrollo nuevo (Con las mismas características que otras - Mismo equipo y misma versión de Access) me da el siguiente error:

> Error de sintaxis en la clausula FROM

en la linea `Reader = DBCmd.ExecuteReader` y en Access esa instrucción funciona bien, Que creen que sucede?

La otra: El "End Funcion" me dice que la función no regresa un valor.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o idea.

Answer (score 1):

En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta, tienes esta línea

```
If Not Rslt Then Exit Function
```

En ese caso, no estas efectivamente retornando ningun valor. Deberías modificarlo por:

```
If Not Rslt Then Return False;
```

En cuanto a la primera, `User` es una [palabra reservada de Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe), así que en ese caso si `User` es el nombre de la tabla, debe ir entre corchetes. Prueba con:

```
DBCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Login_Name='" + ID + "' And Password='" + Psw + "'"
```

Comment: Gracias por lo de primera pregunta Pikoh, la segunda aún con tu indicación sigue igual. Aprecio tu ayuda.

Comment: @MaximilianoGilToro puede ser por tener el  `Application.Exit()` en uno de los if. Prueba a comentar esa linea y poner `Return False`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Pikoh

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Maximiliano? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde y te dará 2 puntos de reputación). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!